# Doctrine Query Builder not working with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, query-builder

I have the following code in a function in one of my controllers:

```
$qb = $this->doctrine->em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('username, password, level')
    ->from('User', 'u');
        // ->where('user.username = :username')
        // ->setParameter('username', 'userTest');
$users = $query->getResult();
```

which causes *something* to fail silently.  No error message, the only thing I get from the page is a 500 server error.  If I comment out the `$users = $query->getResult()` line the page loads just fine, so it seems that the query builder is just not working here.  I have no idea why though.  Do I need to somehow load it in my Doctrine.php library file?  I don't think so.

Another odd thing I've discovered is if I try to retrieve entries via the `getRepository` method it prints out DQL statement to the output of the page, as in that method itself for some reason prints out a DQL statement.  I do not take the result of it and print it out.

Any idea what's going on here?  My User class is pretty simple.  Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong as there's no error being reported.  D:

```
<?php
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EmailAddress", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $emails;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a step !

Look the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query).

Try : `$users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();`

And change : `$qb->select('u.username, u.password, u.level')`

Comment: I did take a look at the documentation, but I don't think that's the correct code.  Shouldn't it be `$qb->getQuery()->getResult()`? (this still results in me getting a HTTP 500 server error though)

Additionally, trying your line does not work.  I still get a HTTP 500 server error when I have `$users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();` uncommented.

Comment: It is the same  cause your assign `$query` with `$qb`. 
Try : `$qb->select('u.username, u.password, u.level')`, I will udpate my answer if it is working

Comment: That works!  Thanks!  I also discovered that it was printing out DQL because I had an EchoSQLLogger setup in Doctrine's configuration.